# Stuck in error loop between Data cardinality is ambiguous and shapes are incompatible with my 3d cnn model

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm attempting to train my model using the "train_on_batch" function, as the data is too large to be fully put in at once. The shape of my training data is as follows: X.shape = (388, 108, 36, 36, 36), Y.shape = (388, 108). To make the data clear, there are 388 x and 388 y train files. Each of these training files contains 108 arrays of 3d arrays (36,36,36). For every 3d array, there is a corresponding binary. I'm trying to iterate through these 388 pairs of files 1 by 1 to use in the train_on_batch. Below is the CNN model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3,3), padding='valid', input_shape=(108, 36, 36, 36)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2,2,2)))
model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3,3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2,2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

This was my first for loop for trying to input the data:

```
for i in range(len(X_train)):
     model.train_on_batch(X_train[i], Y_train[i], sample_weight=None)
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 108, 36, 36, 36), found shape=(108, 36, 36, 36)
```

To combat this I reshaped my data, which resulted in my input being accepted. I ensured that the y data was the same shape, however then I reached the error loop which I cannot figure out myself, and wanted to ask others. Here is the reshape resulting in `ValueError: Shapes (1, 108) and (1, 2) are incompatible`:

```
for i in range(len(X_train)):
     new_X_train = X_train[i].reshape(1, 108, 36, 36, 36)
     new_Y_train = Y_train[i].reshape(1, 108)
```

When I apply `.astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))` on the Y, then I get the error that `ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:`. This makes sense to me because since then the x and y data won't be the same format.

The output should be 0 or 1, as these are ct_scan slices, so it's identifying the array as either "nodule" or "non-nodule". For reference, here is what Y_train[0] looks like:

```
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while. There are many questions that can help me solve my errors, but my issue is when I solve "Data cardinality is ambiguous", I get sent to the "shapes are incompatible". Vise-verca. I might be missing something, I tried what several threads have done with these individual problems but I can't seem to figure it out. Is it just the data format that my training files are in?

Comment: Each sample input should be (32,32,32,1) and 388 *108 should be the total samples. Once you convert the inputs to (388*108,32,32,32,1) and labels to (388*108), use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` to create a dataset and then you can batch it. Use `model.fit` to do batch training. Check: https://keras.io/examples/vision/3D_image_classification/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was misinterpreting a comment I had read while following a guide on how to setup this model. By writing (108,36,36,36) instead of (36,36,36,1) I was telling the model the incorrect input shape. Once that was fixed, it worked.